# How delete rows that are not in a specific time period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, row

Is there any way to delete all the rows that 'datetime' is not within"08:30:00.000 to 14:59"

Following are some rows of my table:

```
open    high    low close   volume  datetime
277.14  277.51  276.71  276.8799    968908  2020-04-13 08:30:00.000
245.3   246.06  245.2   246.01  1094537 2020-04-01 14:48:00.000
285.12  285.27  284.81  285.22  534427  2020-04-27 08:30:00.000
246.08  246.08  245.27  245.46  1333257 2020-04-01 14:50:00.000
291.71  291.73  291.08  291.28  1439183 2020-04-30 08:30:00.000
245.89  246.63  245.64  246.25  960411  2020-04-01 14:52:00.000
285.18  285.4   285 285.36  188531  2020-04-27 08:32:00.000
285.79  285.79  285.65  285.68  6251    2020-05-14 18:59:00.000
246.25  246.56  246.12  246.515 956339  2020-04-01 14:54:00.000
```

I only need the rows that  08:30<='datetime'<15:00,no matter in which day.Currently I found there are lots of rows is out of the time range 08:30-14:59,so I want to find a fast way to delete all the rows are out of this range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting based on a time range:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONVERT(time, datetime) < '08:30:00' OR CONVERT(time, datetime) >= '15:00:00';
```

Comment: So this command will delete all row from 08:30 to 15:00?but what I want is to delete the rows that are out of this range.Really appreciate your reply.

Comment: @William Sorry, I guess I misunderstood your requirement.  I have updated my answer, see above.